# Embed binary build tools in CRAN packages?

Tags: r, rust, rust-cargo

I am building a **Rust** extension mechanism for **R** (and vice versa).

For those who have not encountered it, Rust is a modern language that
enables you to build multi-threaded computationally intensive code
concisely and embed domain specific languages (like R) in the compiler.

I would therefore need to embed the **cargo** package manager as a binary
or link in a **CRAN** package in order to build Rust-derived extensions
"out of the box" from Rust source in the case that cargo is not already installed.

https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo

Could someone in the R community shed light on how to achieve this in the correct
manner or point me at a CRAN package that does something similar? Is it considered legitimate to install cargo from a link and how would we handle Windows and Mac installs?

Comment: CRAN policy says "Source packages may not contain any form of binary executable code." Usually, you would list cargo under `SystemRequirements` in your DESCRIPTION file and leave installation to the user (see the [rJava package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rJava) for an example). You could also provide an R function that (when called by the user) does the installation for the user (if that is feasible).

Comment: What @Roland said is the most "R-way" to do it, many packages like rJava (jre), magick (imagemagick), animation (ffmpeg) do it this way. Licence wise I think it would be no problem to include the rust compiler and cargo in an R-package, MIT licence is one of the more common R-licences.

Comment: Many thanks. I am anxious to meet the expectations of R users in this regard. I'll take a good look at rJava. The idea of providing an installation function for cargo is a good one.